# How to mock json services that I rails app depends on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, integration-testing

If my rails application makes calls to different API's (json based), what options do I have in terms of creating mocks for these?

I saw a video where someone opened up a terminal and actual ran a script that created mocks for these services, but it was running another process that did this not within your rspec code etc.

Does anyone know what that could have been?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the VCR gem: https://github.com/vcr/vcr.

It is also described in this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr